# Android blurry screen sometimes

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, blurry

This device:
https://www.amazon.de/Sony-Tablet-PC-Touchscreen-GHz-Quad-Core-Prozessor-interner/dp/B00IN1N66I

- Sony Xperia Tablet Z2 SGP511 (10,1") Tablet-PC (Touchscreen, 2,3
  GHz-Quad-Core-Prozessor, 3GB RAM, 16GB)
- Android version 5.1.1 (Lollipop)

I'm developing an app with cordova (hybrid) and the screen gets blurry sometimes for no appearant reason.

This usually goes away when I tap the screen in a random place inside the div or element that is blurry.

**Blurry:**

[image]

=============================================

**Clear:**

[image]

Comment: are you remotely debugging with android device ?

Comment: Yes I sure am..

Comment: @HassanALi When the tablet is disconnected from the computer the issue does not occur, go give an answer and i'll accept it and upvote it for future people to see ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The application gets blurry only while remotely debugging the android device. So it isn't an issue or some error. Blur goes away either when tapping the application or by disconnecting the device from the computer.